# How can I implement "weak" edges with NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx, topological-sort

### Background

I am writing a Python module to collect and schedule tasks for a nightly automatic update, with the option to interactively execute individual tasks. (The nightly updates run all tasks unconditionally.)

- Some of these individual tasks depend on the *execution* of another task to function properly: e.g. if task A is scheduled (automatically or manually) but task B is not, then task B must be added to the schedule before A.  I'm referring to these as **strong dependencies**, because they "pull in" a new task if necessary.
- Other tasks depend on the *output* of another task, but can also operate on old output if that task is not scheduled; e.g. if task C is scheduled but task D is not, then D is *not* added, and C runs on old data.  I'm referring to these as **weak dependencies**, because they're "too weak" to make changes to the schedule.

I've successfully implemented strong dependencies using `nx.DiGraph` to build the dependency relationships and `nx.topological_sort` to generate the final task schedule (with the requested tasks as the starting nodes).  I'm unsure how to implement weak dependencies, however, because `topological_sort` seems to always add nodes connected by any edge.  I've even tried setting the edges' `weight` to 0, but no luck.

#### Implementation

**EDIT:** Here's a rough example of my current implementation.

```py
# tasklib.py
task_graph = nx.DiGraph()

def run(start_tasks):
    global task_graph

    for modname in glob.glob('modules/*.py'):
        __import__(os.path.splitext(modname)[0].replace('/','.'))

    task_queue = nx.topological_sort(task_graph, start_tasks)

    # Remove weakly-linked tasks here

    for t in task_queue:
        task_graph.node[t]['func']()

def task(func):
    task_graph.add_node(func.__name__, func=func)
    return func

def depends(*args): # strong dependency
    def add_deps(func):
        for dep in args:
            task_graph.add_edge(func.__name__, dep)
        return func
    return add_deps

def after(*args): # weak dependency
    def add_deps(func):
        for dep in args:
            task_graph.add_edge(func.__name__, dep, weak=True)
        return func
    return add_deps


# modules/mytasks.py
from tasklib import task, depends, after

@task
def process_data():
    # do some lengthy processing

@task
@depends('process_data')
def process_more_data():
    # do even more processing on the above output

@task
@after('process_data')
def generate_report():
    # generate a report on the processed data
```

Here, `process_more_data` needs up-to-date output from `process_data` before it can continue the job, so it uses a strong dependency.  On the other hand, `generate_report` can do so using old data if run by itself, but if `process_data` is also scheduled, it doesn't make sense to generate a report on old data when new results are about to be produced; it shouldn't run until afterward.

Based on @BrenBarn's suggestion, I will probably try adding an additional step to `run` that removes weakly-linked tasks from `task_queue` unless they also exist in `start_tasks`.

### Question

What my question boils down to is:  Can I make edges that participate in the sort *only* if both nodes are in the starting node set?  If so, how?  If not, is there an alternative method or library that *will* achieve this effect?

I've considered writing a stripped-down network library with this feature for my own purposes, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

#### Extra Credit

Besides the above, I'd also like to support "post-dependencies," where one task implies that a dependency task runs *after* it — but I fear this is beyond the scope of a mere topo sort.

Comment: I wouldn't differentiate these dependencies and just return the old data from a task when it hasn't run before when linked from a weak depending task.

Comment: If I understand right, it seems like it might make more sense to do this as part of the creation of the graph.  That is, when adding task C, if task D is not in the graph, you don't add it; if it is, you an add edge to it.  Just don't add edges in the first place for weak dependencies if the "optional dependency" is not present in the graph.

Comment: Also, if you can set the edge weight to 0, can't you just remove the edge instead?

Comment: @orange The data is on disk, not passed around or returned, and the tasks themselves don't "know about" the network, they are just tagged with dependencies.  @BrenBarn As it stands, I don't have total control over the order tasks and dependencies are added.  They are created by function decorators in a number of other modules, each task tagged with the names of those it depends on, like so: `@task @depends('dep1','dep2') def taskname(): ...`  I suppose I could do that in a preprocessing step, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to build a dependency graph containing a directed edge between `A` and `B` if and only if `A` strongly depends upon `B`, or `A` weakly depends upon `B` and `B` is strongly depended upon by some other task.

Here's some code that does just that. In this example, we'll consider six tasks, `a` through `f`:

```
import networkx as nx

deps = nx.DiGraph()
deps.add_nodes_from("abcdef")
deps.add_edges_from([("a","b"), ("c","a"), ("e","c")], is_strong=True)
deps.add_edges_from([("f","c"), ("d","c")], is_strong=False)
```

We can read this as `a` is a strong requirement of `b`, etc., and `f` is a weak requirement of `c`. The user will select tasks `a` and `c` to run. Since task `a` runs, we'll need `c` to run before it, and therefore also need `e` to run before `c`. Task `d` has no strong dependencies, but it is a weak dependency of `c`. Hence we'll want to run the tasks in the order: `d, e, c, a`.

First we'll extract the subgraph induced by throwing out all weak edges. We'll look at the ancestors of each scheduled task in this graph: this is the set of dependencies that we *need* to run. Then We'll just take the subgraph of the full dependency graph induced by these nodes. A topo sort on this graph yields our desired solution.

Here's the code:

```
def construct_task_graph(deps, tasks):
    required = set(tasks)
    strong_subgraph = extract_strong_subgraph(deps)
    for task in tasks:
        ancestors = nx.ancestors(strong_subgraph, task)
        required.update(ancestors)

    return nx.subgraph(deps, required)

def extract_strong_subgraph(deps):
    strong_deps = nx.DiGraph()
    strong_deps.add_nodes_from(deps)

    strong_edges = (e for e in deps.edges_iter(data=True) if e[2]["is_strong"])
    strong_deps.add_edges_from(strong_edges)

    return strong_deps
```

Note that `construct_task_graph` is a bit inefficient: tasks may be ancestors of tasks which were processed in earlier iterations, yielding duplicate requirements. These are thrown out by the set, but a more efficient way would be to implement something like a DFS.

In any case, we get:

```
>>> task_graph = construct_task_graph(deps, ["a", "d"])
>>> task_graph.nodes()
['a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
>>> task_graph.edges()
[('c', 'a'), ('e', 'c'), ('d', 'c')]
```

and most importantly:

```
>>> nx.topological_sort(task_graph)
['d', 'e', 'c', 'a']
```

Comment: Your graph-fu is far superior to my own! :)  I hadn't even considered using two graphs.  I'll see about implementing this tomorrow (no access to the code at the moment).